# Failed to Load ESLint Plugin 'next' Despite Correct Configuration in Next.js Project

Tags: json, next.js, eslint

I've been integrating ESLint with my Next.js project and have run into an issue that I can't seem to solve. I followed the official Next.js documentation for setting up ESLint and added the configuration as mentioned. However, when I try to lint my project, I encounter the following error:

```
error - ESLint: Failed to load plugin 'next' declared in '.eslintrc.json':
Cannot find module 'E:\Project\node_modules\eslint-plugin-next\index.js'.
Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
Require stack: - E:\Project\__placeholder__.js
```

**To debug the issue:**

- I've confirmed that the eslint-plugin-next is properly installed as a dev dependency in my project.
- I checked the `node_modules/eslint-plugin-next` directory, and strangely, it only contains a package.json file with no actual implementation files.
- I tried deleting the node_modules directory and the lock files (package-lock.json or yarn.lock) and reinstalling the dependencies, but the problem persists.
- I manually installed `eslint-plugin-next` using `npm`, but still no luck.
- I'm unsure what's causing this and why the necessary files for the plugin are not present in the node_modules directory.

**eslintrc.json:**

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "next/core-web-vitals"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier", "import", "jsx-a11y","next"],
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 2],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "semi": ["error", "always"],
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "no-unused-prop-types": "error",
    "react-in-jsx-scope": "error",
    "prop-types": "error",
    "react/prop-types": "error",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": ["error", { "extensions": [".jsx", ".tsx"] }],
    "react/no-unused-state": "error",
    "next/no-html-link-for-pages": "off",
    "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": "error",
    "react/jsx-no-undef": "error",
    "react/no-unknown-property": "error",
    "react/self-closing-comp": "error",
    "jsx-a11y/alt-text": "error",
    "jsx-a11y/no-onchange": "error",
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "error",
    "prefer-arrow-callback": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error",
    "import/no-unresolved": "error",
    "import/no-duplicates": "error",
    "import/order": "error",
    "no-console": "error",
    "@next/next/google-font-display": "error",
    "@next/next/google-font-preconnect": "error",
    "@next/next/inline-script-id": "error",
    "@next/next/next-script-for-ga": "error",
    "@next/next/no-assign-module-variable": "error",
    "@next/next/no-async-client-component": "error",
    "@next/next/no-before-interactive-script-outside-document": "error",
    "@next/next/no-css-tags": "error",
    "@next/next/no-document-import-in-page": "error",
    "@next/next/no-duplicate-head": "error",
    "@next/next/no-head-element": "error",
    "@next/next/no-head-import-in-document": "error",
    "@next/next/no-html-link-for-pages": "error",
    "@next/next/no-img-element": "error",
    "@next/next/no-page-custom-font": "error",
    "@next/next/no-script-component-in-head": "error",
    "@next/next/no-styled-jsx-in-document": "error",
    "@next/next/no-sync-scripts": "error",
    "@next/next/no-title-in-document-head": "error",
    "@next/next/no-typos": "error",
    "@next/next/no-unwanted-polyfillio": "error"
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"]
      }
    },
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

**package.json:**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^12.3.4",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.8.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.8.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1135.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "cypress": "^12.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.1.6",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-next": "^0.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^13.0.0",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
```